# Powershell script check the status of the stopped services and send mail

Tags: powershell

I am pretty new  to Powershell scripting and i have a requirement to check the status of the services, if the services are stopped ,capture the status into a separate text file and send the  email status to the users that services got stopped. In my environment services runs on two different machines . How to achieve it using Get -service

Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Aside from Jeff's remarks, your question is ambiguous. What does `the status of **the** services` mean?  Also `the users that services got stopped` is misleading - services relate primarily to a computer and everyone of them has services running.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you haven't started, I'll give you a few things to kick you off.

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.status -eq "stopped"}
```

This is a way to retrieve all the stopped services. `Get-Service` gets all the services, `Where-Object` is like an if statement in programming, and the part in parenthesis is the condition to meet.

Here's a link where you can read more about that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176858.aspx

This is a line of code that will write processes to a text file:

```
Get-Process | Out-File c:\scripts\test.txt
```

You can see how combining different commands will get you the result you want. Search around the internet if you get stuck. PowerShell is pretty well documented.

Here's a link for some more research on writing to a file: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx